# "findById is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have written this code and tried to delete the posts of a user while deleting the user's account. Now, findById is working fine foe the user but when I'm trying to delete the posts inside a loop it's showing that findById is not a function. please suggest something.

This is the user controller. I have added all the user functions here. In the end, there is deleteMyProfile()... that's the function that is having error. please suggest me how an I fix this.

```
const User = require("../models/User");
const Post = require("../controllers/post")

exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    try{

        const {name,email,password} =  req.body;

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (user){
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ success:false, message:"User aleady Exists" })
        }

        user = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            avatar:{
                public_id:"sampleid", url: "sampleurl"
            }
        })
        const token = await user.generateToken()

        res
        .status(201)
        .cookie("token",token,{httpOnly:true})
        .json({ success:true,user })
    

    }catch(error){
        res
            .status(500)
            .json({ success:false, message:error.message })
    }
}

exports.login = async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const {email,password} =  req.body;

        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");
        if(!user){
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ success:false, message:"User doesn't Exist" })
        }

        const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password)

        if(!isMatch){
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ success:false, message:"Incorrect Password" })
        }else{

            const token = await user.generateToken()

            res
            .status(200)
            .cookie("token",token,{httpOnly:true})
            .json({ success:true,user })
        }

    }catch(error){
        res
            .status(500)
            .json({ success:false, message:error.message })

    }
}

exports.logout = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        res
        .status(500)
        .cookie("token",null,{expires:new Date(Date.now()),httpOnly:true})
        .json({ success:true, message:"logged out" })
    } catch (error) {
        res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success:false, message:error.message })
    }
}


exports.followUser = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const userToFollow = await User.findById(req.params.id);

        const loggedInUser = await User.findById(req.user._id);

        if(!userToFollow){
            res
            .status(404)
            .json({ success:false, message:"User Doesn't exist" })
        }

        if(loggedInUser.following.includes(userToFollow._id)){

            const indexfollowing = loggedInUser.following.indexOf(userToFollow._id)
            loggedInUser.following.splice(indexfollowing,1)


            const indexfollowers = userToFollow.followers.indexOf(loggedInUser._id)
            userToFollow.followers.splice(indexfollowers,1)


            await loggedInUser.save();
            await userToFollow.save();

            res
            .status(200)
            .json({ success:true,message:"Unfollowed successfully" })
            
        }
        else{
            loggedInUser.following.push(userToFollow._id);
        userToFollow.followers.push(loggedInUser._id);

        await loggedInUser.save();
        await userToFollow.save();

        res
            .status(200)
            .json({ success:true,message:"Followed successfully" })

        }

        

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success:false, message:error.message })
    }
}

exports.updatePassword = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const user =  await User.findById(req.user._id).select("+password");

        const {oldPassword , newPassword} = req.body;

        if(!oldPassword || !newPassword){
            res.status(400).json({ success:false, message:"Please provide password" })
        }

        const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(oldPassword);
        if(!isMatch){
        res.status(400).json({ success:false, message:"Wrong old password" })
        }

        user.password = newPassword;

        await user.save();

        res.status(200).json({ success:true, message:"Password Updated" })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success:false, message:error.message })
    }
}


exports.updateProfile =  async (req,res) => {
   
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

        const {name, email} = req.body;
    
        if(name){
            user.name = name; 
        }
    
        if(email){
            user.email = email;
        }
        await user.save();
    
        res.status(200).json({ success:true, message:"Profile Updated" })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success:false, message:error.message })
        
    }
}

exports.deletemyProfile = async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
        const posts = user.posts;

        await user.deleteOne();
        res
        .cookie("token",null,{expires:new Date(Date.now())});

        for(let i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
            console.log("hi")
            const post = await Post.findById(posts[i]);
            await post.deleteOne();
        }

        res.status(200).json({ success:true, message:"Profile Deleted" })


    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success:false, message:error.message })
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Post` defined?

Comment: Check your import statement. Should that be `const Post = require("../models/post")` instead of `const Post = require("../controllers/post")
`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrtly, change your `import` to import the correct module. I suspect it should be:

```js
const Post = require("../models/Post")
```

Secondly, use `Model.deleteMany()` to delete all of the Posts that were related to the deleted User. This is far more efficient than deleting each Post in a `for` loop. With `deleteMany()` it is done in one single db call whereas in a `for` loop you could potentially make 10s/100s/1000s/...  of database calls, once per `Post._id` so will be terrible for performance:

```js
exports.deletemyProfile = async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        // findByIdAndDelete will delete the User and return the document
        const user = await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.user._id);

        res.cookie("token",null,{expires:new Date(Date.now())});

        // Find all Posts where Post._id IN user.posts array of _id
        await Post.deleteMany({_id: { $in: user.posts }});

        res.status(200).json({ success:true, message:"Profile Deleted" })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success:false, message:error.message })
    }
}
```